# If-else macro in MASM

Tags: x86, masm

In MASM, is it possible to create an if...ekse macro (similar to those found in high-level programming languages)? I haven't yet found any kind of if-else statement macro for MASM, but I think a macro for this purpose would be very useful.

It would be useful if I could find a macro to make it easier to write a complicated series of if-statements in masm, as shown here:

```
;jump to each case here
    checkCase1:
    cmp theVariable, 5;
    jne case1; 

    checkCase2:
    cmp theVariable, var2;
    jne case2;

    jmp defaultCase; do this if no other statement is true
;each of the cases are handled here

    case1:
    ;handle case 1
    jmp checkCase2; //check whether case 2 is true

    case2:
    handle case 2
    jmp endOfStatement;
    defaultCase:
        ;this is the default case
endOfStatement:
;this is the end of the statement
```

Comment: The example that I posted acts more like an if...else if...else statement than a switch statement.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to write a MASM macro that would accept a variable number of arguments. Perhaps it would be easier to write a simple if...else macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nobody reads the manual anymore???  Assembly has been around for YEARS, MASM has been out for YEARS!!!  Tons of samples and documentation!!!

For example:

```
.if eax == 1

.elseif eax !=10

.elseif eax >= 11

.else

.endif
```

MASM32 contains a case macro...

Comment: This is the only documentation I've found so far: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4x287ff(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You could download MASM32: http://masm32.com/ it contains includes, libs macros, sample code, help files...  MASM32 is MASM on steroids

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as below.

```
if preservebx eq 1
    push bx
else
    mov byte ptr [rdx], bl
endif
```

The somewhat terrible reference is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/directives-reference?view=msvc-170