# Intel x86 assembly - lt, gt, eq

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, translate, masm

I am trying to write a translator that translates VM language in Intel x86 assembly language (MASM). Unfortunately I cannot find a proper translation for lt (less than), gt (greater than) or eq (equal), but I would expect that there is something like that in the instruction set.
The closest thing I could find was cmp (compare) followed by a conditioned jump. But nothing without a jump.

For example when I want to translate if (x>1 and x<3) do ... the VM code looks something like

```
push local 0
push constant 1
gt
push local 0
push constant 3
lt
and
if-goto IF_TRUE0
```

my problem is now that I don't know how to translate that gt and lt as they are not directly followed by a jump, but rather are both part of a single jump condition.

Comment: That's how computers generally work.

Comment: Conditional jumps *are* what is used to implement if/else statements and loops on the assembly level on Intel CPUs. What exactly are you after?

Comment: Another option is to use the built-in macros like `.if`, etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351291/56778 for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another conditional jump. A naive translation would be something like

```
        cmp local0, 1
        jle .L1
        cmp local0, 3
        jge .L1
        ;; code of true case
.L1:
```

Note that your translator will have to look a bit further than just the `gt/lt` operation and its arguments to figure out how a comparison should be translated.

Comment: Thank you! That's the only thing I could think of, but it seemed a little complicated, as I would need to look ahead quite a bit (as you already mentioned). Is that the easiest way? Is there really no plain lt/gt in x86 assembly?

Comment: No. However, you can generate a zero-or-one from a condition (using `setcc`) if you like. That will run quite a bit more slowly, but your code generation job may be a little easier.

Comment: Your code above works for AND, but what if the two conditions x>1, x<3 are linked with OR? I'm sure there's a easy solution, but I can't think of anything right now.

Comment: Place a new label `.L2` at the beginning of the true case, and change the first conditional jump to `jg .L2`.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to write a function lessThan that wrappes the code you posted (returns 1 if 1st parameter is smaller, else 0) and to use that instead of lt in x86?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the translation automatically (you want to write something like a JIT compiler) you have to think about how the "gt" instruction works:

Example for "GT":

```
Stack before: X, Y, ...
Stack after: 1, ... if (X<Y)
```

You need multiple x86 instructions for one "LT" instruction. Example:

```
  pop ax  ; this is X
  pop cx  ; this is Y
  xor dx,dx ; set edx to 0
  cmp cx,ax
  jle some_label
  mov dx,1
some_label:
  push dx
```

Using 32-bit code you may use the "setgt" instruction:

```
pop eax  ; this is X
pop ecx  ; this is Y
xor edx,edx ; set edx to 0
cmp ecx,eax
setgt dl
push edx
```